# Postgres - searching query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Hello i am trying to make a searching tool for links.
But when my query face with (/) return no result.

```
SELECT source FROM streams
where source::text ilike '%http://:999/Users-personal/ezample23456789/2520512%';
```

When i try to find 'http' is working fine
[image: Picture1]

The column is json

Comment: I can not reproduce. Looks as your data store escaped slashes strings https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/fd70eb586461d258434d312b7506bd2e/

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query.

```
SELECT source FROM streams where source::text ilike '%http%://:999/Users-personal/ezample23456789/2520512%';
```

Comment: Actually i try like this SELECT source FROM streams
where source::text ilike '%http:%%:999%Users-personal%ezample23456789%2520512%'; and is working good